# Understanding of kafka auto-offset-reset

Tags: apache-kafka

I read that the default experation time of kafka offsets are 7 days.
Is my understanding correct for the following scenario?

1. Producer produces message 1 and 2
2. Consumer with **auto-offset-reset=latest** consumes messages 1 and 2 with commit

Nothings happens for 6 days

3. Consumer crashes
4. Producer produces message 3

Nothings happens for 2 days

5. Consumer is starting but doesnt read message 3, because the last committed offset is deleted
   and **auto-offset-reset=latest** is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

**Offset expiration** [Additional Upgrade Notes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_1_0)

> According to the new semantics, **offsets of partitions in a group will not be removed while the group is subscribed to the corresponding topic and is still active (has active consumers)**. If group becomes empty all its offsets will be removed after default offset retention period (or the one set by broker) has passed (unless the group becomes active again)

The consumer group offset will be removed when there are no active consumers in that group for 7 days of period (default retention).

When consumer crashes, that means there are no active consumers in that group and if the consumer is crashed for 7 days then offset will be removed.

Once the offset data is deleted/not found, then if any consumer subscribes will take the configs provided. If the `auto-offset-reset=latest` then it will just consume the data published after the consumer is initialized.

**auto.offset.reset** [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset)

> What to do when there is **no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more** on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

Comment: I read that, but our offsets are definetly removed after 7 days independend from the consumers. Your answer doesnt fit for my scenario.

Comment: @JavaQuestioner123 That is default Kafka behavior, and has nothing to do with Consumer or client properties

Answer (score 0):

Committed offsets have different configuration on the broker than the topic retention.

Review Kafka settings between `retention.ms` topic config and `offsets.retention.minutes`

**However** - You need to understand that only **closed segments** are deleted, and segments have a default size of 1GB. Meaning, if you only sent 3 events, with an average size less than `333.33 MB` (while Kafka records individually only have a max-limit of 1MB, by default), then you will still have all 3 events being retained in the open segment, regardless of time...

---

In any case, yes, if the consumer group offsets are removed (as if the group never existed), then `auto.offset.reset` takes place. Note: `none` is a valid option for this setting if you want to throw an exception for when this occurs, rather than seeking to the end of the topic, and potentially skipping data you may have read before.

Also, if the topic data is un-retained and you get "offset-out-of-range" exceptions, the property is also used.